# Sample paths of B.M are not monotonic in any interval.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, monotone-functions

Is this an ok proof for a.s no  interval of monotonicity for sample paths of B.M

EDIT : [In the proceeding proof I just prove the sample path is not strictly increasing, it is an equivalent proof to show it is not strictly decreasing ]

first we show for the interval [0,1]

$P(B(t)-B(s)\geq 0$ $ \forall s,t\in [0,1]) $

$\leq P(B(\frac{i+1}{n})-B(\frac{i}{n})\geq0 $  for $i =0,...n-1$ )= $\frac{1}{2^n}$ $\to 0 $

now we use scaling properties and stationary increments to prove for rational intervals [p,q]

consider for , p,q rational

$P(B(t)-B(s)\geq 0$ $ \forall s,t\in [p,q]) $

$=P(B(t-p)-B(s-p)\geq 0$ $ \forall s,t\in [p,q]) $ by stationary property

$=P(B(t)-B(s)\geq 0$ $ \forall s,t\in [0,q-p]) $

$=P((\frac{1}{q-p})^{-1/2}B(t\frac{1}{q-p})-(\frac{1}{q-p})^{-1/2}B(s\frac{1}{q-p})\geq 0$ $ \forall s,t\in [0,q-p])$ by scaling property

$=P(B(t)-B(s)\geq 0$ $ \forall s,t\in [0,1]) $

edit: If we have no monitancity in all rational intervals then we have no monotonicity in any arbitrary interval since all rational intervals contain such arbitrary intervals.

Comment: No the first inequality is wrong and about the second part what is it for ? The first term is equal to last, so you have circled around without achieving anything

Comment: With the string of equalities we show that P(monotonic in [0,1]) is equivalent to P(monotonic in any rational interval) ... and before this we proved that P( B.M  monotonic in [0,1]) =0  therefore we have that it is not monotonic in rational intervals.

Comment: How does the first inequality not hold? the 2nd events are a subset of the first?

Comment: For the first point: take an interval t_0,t_2 subdivide it in 2 equal part (t_0, t_1=(t_0+t_2)/2) and  (t_1, t_2). then you have the event $A =[B_{t_1} -B_{t_0}  >0 ] \cap [B_{t_2} -B_{t_1}  >0 ]$ that is included in $B=[B_{t_2} -B_{t_0}  >0 ]$.

Comment: The inclusion you provide above is true but says nothing about the inclusion that my proof is using...

Comment: @TheBridge would you agree with this : $P(B(t)$ is monotonically (increasing) in $(0,1))$ $ \leq P(B(\frac{i+1}{n})-B(\frac{i}{n})\geq0 $  for $i =0,...n-1$ )

Comment: You are right I misread the "forall" part of the left event,sorry about that this part is absolutly correct ! (by the way how do you know this event is measurable ?).Your second part is clumsy IMO, because the same argument as your proof in the first part works fine for any p,q in $\mathbb {R}^+$ (and is more direct).Using rational endpoints intervals (which appears in proof in most lecture you can find) is useless unless mistaken, you have already made your point, as p,q are not fixed, it is true for any interval so there is no interval with monotonic path with postiive probability.